# Why do I need to bother setting up CSRF if Spring Security CorsFilter will anyways reject the request before it reaches controller?

Tags: spring-security, cors, csrf

So with my configuration, where I specify CORS but turn off CSRF protection:

```java
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .cors(c -> {
                    CorsConfigurationSource source = request -> {
                        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                        config.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200"));
                        config.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
                        config.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
                        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
                        return config;
                    };
                    c.configurationSource(source);
                })
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(customizer -> customizer.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .build();
    }
```

I tried to make a request with HTML form (because forms are not blocked by browser CORS) from localhost:3000 (not allowed origin):

```html
<form action="http://localhost:8080/resource" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="bad_actor@example.com">
    <button type="submit">Submit with CSRF</button>
</form>
```

Expectedly Spring Security's `CorsFilter` rejects the request, and I got 403 response:

```java
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = this.configSource.getCorsConfiguration(request);
        boolean isValid = this.processor.processRequest(corsConfiguration, request, response);
        if (!isValid || CorsUtils.isPreFlightRequest(request)) {
            return; // rejected here, never reaches the controller
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

With this in mind, why do we even bother with CSRF protection if Spring's `CorsFilter` will anyways block it?

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, [CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is [_not_ a defence](https://twitter.com/annevk/status/948831079649169408); its purpose is not to _block_ requests, but to _relax_ the reading (and, in some cases, sending) restrictions that the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) enforces by default in browsers.

Comment: @jub0bs That doesn't answer my question, not sure what the point of your comment is? I am not here to discuss difference between CSRF and CORS, my question is specific to Spring Security and it's CorsFilter implementation.

Comment: My point is that relying on CORS as a defence against CSRF is a mistake.

Comment: What I want to understand is the WHY behind it. If Spring Security's CorsFilter effectively mitigates the CSRF problem, why (or is it) a recommendation to still set up CSRF protection with Spring Security? Imo there is no right or wrong in computer programming, it is important to understand why something is applicable to this situation.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the implementation of Spring Security's CorsFilter. It may well block requests coming from Web origins disallowed by your CORS configuration. But this is indeed what happens, that would be a perversion of the CORS protocol.

Comment: In case of [_simple_ requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests), the server cannot (in general) determine whether the request participates in the CORS protocol. In fact, your form submission does not. Therefore, the CORS filter should logically let it pass through.

Comment: The server sinply blocks it because it comes from a different origin than the one allowed, and since CSRF attacks are always from a different origin it effectively neutralizes the porblem. So even though the browser would have let it through, the Server (Spring Security) does not. But I understand ur point.

Comment: I hadn't realised until your question (thanks!) that `CorsFilter` blocks all requests from disallowed origins. I think that warrants opening a GitHub issue. A filter may well implement some CSRF protection by inspecting the value of the `Origin` header, but doing this shouldn't be the responsibility of a filter that deals with CORS.